# Knowing the reason of DLL loading failed for Windows Store App

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I tried to use [EmguCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) library in Windows 8 Store App. Previously, it works fine for a Windows 7 Desktop App project.

I ensure my Windows 8 Store App project directory [*C:\Projects\App2\App2\bin\Debug*] is having all the necessary DLLs file.

[image]

When I execute directly in *Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate* through *Local Machine*  button, I get the following exception.

[image]

> Exception:Thrown: "Unable to load DLL 'opencv_core240': The specified
>   module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"
>   (System.DllNotFoundException) A System.DllNotFoundException was
>   thrown: "Unable to load DLL 'opencv_core240': The specified module
>   could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"

**My question is** : How can I know whether the failure is caused by my Windows 8 Store App **unable to locate the DLL files**? Or, the located DLL files is **not in the format expected** by Windows 8 Store App? (The DLLs are OK for Windows 7 desktop software)

If the reason is caused by the format is not recognized by Windows 8 Store App, does re-compile the whole DLL project (The OpenCV source code is in C++, and EmguCV which acts as a wrapper is in C#) under *Windows Store -> Class Library (Windows Store apps)* will help?

Comment: It is possible that your app is able to load opencv_core240.dll but then this DLL in turn depends on some other DLL (like VC++ runtime DLLs) because of which it is unable to load even the OpenCV DLL.  More information at this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894063/use-old-c-c-library-with-windows-8-metro-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these dlls worked for Windows 7 desktop apps, then they won't work for Windows 8 Metro apps, because it's completely different platform and API. You cannot load just any dll in your Windows 8 WinRT project.

If you have source code for the dll, you can try to recompile it as a Windows Runtime Component, byt there is a strong possibility the original code used APIs not available in WinRT.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following two posts to see how OpenCV or other 3rd party libraries can be made to work with Windows 8 Store apps:

[Using OpenCV in a Windows Store app with Visual C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065370/using-opencv-in-a-windows-8-store-app-with-visual-c-2012)

[Using a C++ Library (built using Visual C++ 2010) in a Windows 8 Store app (built using Visual C++ 2012)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088917/using-a-c-library-built-using-visual-c-2010-in-a-windows-8-store-app)