# Use old C/C++ library with windows 8 metro app

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm trying to create an application (in C#) for Windows 8 / Windows Phone 8 using an open-source library ([Linphone](http://www.linphone.org/)) written in C/C++.
I tried importing it in VS11, no success.
I have all .dll files that could be needed.

Is there a way to create my app using this library with or without VS11?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is Visual Studio 11?  The only version of Visual Studio that supports Modern UI applications is Visual Studio 2012.  Your are going to need to recompile the library in order to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use binaries built using older version of Visual Studio (older than Visual Studio 2012) in your Windows 8 Store apps.

The reason for that is because a binary built using say Visual Studio 2010 will have a dependency on the C++ Runtime DLLs from Visual Studio 2010.  Whereas the rest of your app is written using Visual Studio 2012 so it will have a dependency on C++ Runtime DLLs from Visual Studio 2012.  The latter is made automatically available from the Windows Store ([read this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/09/28/10354327.aspx) for more details).  However the former is not available on the Windows Store.  Also, there is no way for your app to express a dependency on VC2010 Runtime.  Including VC2010 Runtime DLLs inside the app package will also not work since the package will be rejected at Store upload time.

Therefore the best option is to build all sources for your Windows 8 Store app strictly using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: As I said in the comments of my post, VS11 is Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: I know that.  Did you build the C++ library also with VS11?

Comment: Yes as a matter of fact I did.

Answer (score -1):

You don't "import" unmanaged dll's. Instead, you use PINvoke to call their methods.

See this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx

Comment: While this answer is technically correct, a WinRT Application cannot import non-WinRT dlls, thus making this answer incorrect.

Comment: In the article they said:
The P/Invoke features covered in this month's column are sufficient to call many of the API functions in Windows. However, if your interop needs are significant, you will eventually find yourself marshaling complex data structures and perhaps even needing access to memory directly through pointers in managed code. In fact, interop into native code can be a veritable Pandora's box of details and low-level bits.

I need a lot of bi-directional interactions with my lib...

Comment: Do I have to do `[DllImport("C_DLL.dll", EntryPoint="DoSomethingInC")]
public static extern void DoSomethingInC(ushort ExampleParam, char AnotherExampleParam);` for each function in my dlls (like in JNI) ?

Comment: Yes, you need to declare every native function. Sorry, I missed the fact you are using win8, i don't have experience in that area, maybe your dll's might be constructed in some special way..

Comment: So "basically" I create a WinRT component in C++ using my dlls and defining every function as extern, and I import this component into my C# app ?

Comment: If by import you mean applying a DllImport attribute, yes.

Comment: No I was talking about the WinRT component using my dlls. The WinRT component is the one using DllImport.