# Compile C++ sources to use them in Windows Store app (Windows 8)

Tags: c#, c++, windows-8, windows-store-apps

First of all, I know almost nothing of C++ so please bear with me here.

I'm building a Windows 8 app with C#/XAML (for compatibility with the older devices, I'm not targeting Windows 8.1) and I've been given by the client the sources of a C++ library (header and source files, I mean) to decrypt datain a proprietary format. This library has been used in the iOS version of the app.

As per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894063/use-old-c-c-library-with-windows-8-metro-app) I understand that I should compile the C++ files targeting the Windows Runtime and then use P/Invoke to call the functions I need. I've been researching and tried to follow several guides with no success: like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh699881.aspx). [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx) or [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn769142.aspx). In the last case I couldn't find the cl.exe compiler even if I have both VS 2012 and 2013 installed in my system.

So, is there a dummy-safe way to compile external C++ sources to use them from a C#/XAML Windows 8 app?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: "Dummy-safe"? Probably not. There are a number of "gotchas" when trying to mix managed and unmanaged code. Per the research you've done already, you do need to make sure you're using the latest version of VS and targeting the right CRT DLLs. Also note that you need to compile for the right processor. IMHO, it would be better if you could convert the C++ code to C++/CLI (i.e. mixed-mode managed C++). Then your C++ is compiled to a managed assembly which you can use like any other managed assembly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! You're right, there seems to be no easy way (as I naively thought at the beginning) to use the C++ library as is. Also, the problem with VS2013 is it targets Windows 8.1 not Windows 8. Anyway, I tried to dive into the code and saw that it uses file handles which are not allowed in the Windows Runtime so I'll follow your advice and reimplement the parts I need in C# (I don't know C++/CLI very well). Luckily, it seems it's not that much at the end. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create a new project in VS and then copy the headers and sources in. You can either create a DLL project to pinvoke or a Windows Runtime Component to reference. The latter's generally easier to use, but you'll need to define the interface to call into. You should have cl.exe in your Visual Studio install dir in Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\Bin\, but if you're not familiar with it you'll probably find it much easier to use the IDE.

Windows Store apps don't use C++/CLI, so you won't want to convert to that. They use native code for C++, not managed. If you create a Windows Runtime Component with C++/CX then the boundary interfaces will need to be C++/CX, but the internals can all be standard C++. The WRC will get projected into .Net so it gets called like a managed class from C#.

File handles should be fine (depending on what you mean by file handles). If you're using standard C++ classes then you will have access to pretty much the normal set of C++ file API. You won't have access to the file system outside of the application data and install directories, but you can use C++ file operators in those areas. For others you'll need to use a StorageFile broker.